# How does the Make Dupli-Face tool work?

Tags: modeling

First, i know how to do dupli face. But the problem is, this doesn't involve the Make Dupli-Face tool at all. And even the manual for the Make Dupli Face tool describes a workflow that does not involve to click at the Dupli face tool. http://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/duplifaces.html

It's basically two steps. Parenting, and then simply change for the child object from None to Faces in the Duplication panel in the Properties editor. And that's it. Nothing else. The Make Dupli-Face tool is not touched.

And so this tool riddles me. It does nothing. It is not involved in the process at all. What do i miss here? How is the TOOL called Make Dupli-Face meant to work? What should happen when i click at the menu item? Is this operator a disfunctional obsolete fragment from the past? Or does it have a use?

[image]

Comment: I am leaning toward obsolete operator, as the two step process you describe is all that I can get to work in my investigation.

Comment: Thanks for investigation. The only side effect that i was able to observe is that the object that is marked with Make Dupli-face doesn't render anymore. It's something like an empty for the child objects then ^^